# Всплывающие сообщения на сайтах

Tags: ajax, html, javascript

Как реализовать такие штуки, как например вконтакте - вылетает сообщение снизу, что пришло сообщение или кто-то поставил лайк? Ведь объекта XMLHttpRequest  на стороне клиента, что бы принять ответ, никто не создавал?

Другими словами, если сервер отсылает куда-то запрос, то как его обработать на стороне клиента?

Я когда-то читал про два разных способа. Один - постоянно посылать запросы и проверять, ничего ли не пришло. Вот только это ресурсозатратно и т.д. И был другой способ. Ссылки приветствуются. Развенчание заблуждений - тоже.

Comment: Вконтакт запросы делает раз в полминуты примерно =) Держать постоянное соединение с сервером - это не ня, порты не резиновые. А изредка тыкаться для запросов на пару сотен байт - может и ничего страшного =)

Comment: А есть еще какая-нибудь система? Что бы не отсылать, а ровно тогда, когда нужно получалось? Я что-то читал, но не могу вспомнить...

Comment: Ну, если у вас есть телепатический протокол - можно и с помощью него =D А так... Ну если у человека редко события случаются - можно и пореже спрашивать север об этом. А если чуть ли не каждую минуту - то почаще.

Comment: Тут только что снизу подсказали - comet. Позволяет делать именно то ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COMET

Comment: ОТЛИЧНО! То, что искал. Даже картинки те же.

Comment: http://sontan.name/blog/view/~real-time-web-and-comet - может вы сразу же и подскажете как сделать long-poling?
пишу на java

Comment: если вы имели ввиду JavaScript(судя по тегам вопроса), то вот материалы на русском:
http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet
Если же вы именно про Java, то тут я не могу вам ничем помочь

Comment: Я и на java, и на javascript. Спасибо огромное! Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

Например у битрикса в шапке подключается пролог который проверяет все нужные события для пользователя раз в определенное время.